# Java, Scanner and BlueJ. Something is going stupidly wrong

Tags: java, bluej

That's my first post here. I'm try to run a really simple program and I'm sick of it!

I try to run and just after the second entry it stops. I read somewhere that you have to require input before using any output command. I thought that it was my mistake but not really, everything looks fine (although it is not well written, I was just getting started actually). Anyway, here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class corretorGramatical { 
  public static void main(String [ ] args) {   

     String word;
     String category;
      int i = 0;
      int numberOfWords;
      char code;

       Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("What is the code?");
      code = entry.nextLine().charAt(0);

    switch(code){
        case 'd':

        System.out.println ("How many words do you want to enter");
         numberOfWords = entry.nextInt();
       // entrada.nextLine();


        for(i = 1; i == numberOfWords; numberOfWords--) {
        System.out.println ("What is the word?");
        word = entry.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("What is the category?");
        category = entry.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println (word + ", " + category);
        } 
        break;

case 'g':
        System.out.println ("I only accept d");
        break;

case 'c':
      System.out.println ("I only accept d");
        break;

case 'f':
        System.out.println ("I only accept d");
        break;
  }        
}   
}
```

Comment: Can you reformat the code a bit, it's hard to read.  If you have 4 spaces before each line, it will recognize the paste as code.

Comment: Could you also translate the Portuguese print statements into English?

Comment: Sorry guys, will do it.

Comment: " I read somewhere that you have to require input before using any output command." Can't believe everything you read.

Comment: You still need to do a little work on your post. It's broken up.

Comment: So, one thing I'm noticing is that you don't include an entry.nextLine() after your nextInt(). The following nextLine() will catch the enter key left over from when you enter the integer.

Comment: no really the problem, Monkeygrinder. I put "comment mark" on the line cause I though that was causing the problem.

Comment: I figured this was probably the case, but wanted to make sure you knew that you were actually right to include a nextLine() in the first place. It won't cause the program to fail, but excluding it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad for loop, it doesnt happen.

```
for(i = 1; i == numeroDePalavras; numeroDePalavras--) {
    System.out.println ("Qual é a palavra?");
    palavra = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Qual a categoria?");
    categoria = entry.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println (palavra+categoria);
}
```

Dont know what exactly you want (don't know language), but probably you wanted this:

```
 switch(codigo){
    case 'd':

    System.out.println ("Diga quantas palavras seu dicionario tera");
     numeroDePalavras = entry.nextInt();
   // entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Qual é a palavra?");

    for(i = 1; i < numeroDePalavras; numeroDePalavras--) {
    //Item[] itens = new Item[numeroDePalavras];
    System.out.println ("Qual é a palavra?");
    palavra = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Qual a categoria?");
    categoria = entry.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println (palavra+categoria);
  //  itens[numeroPalavras] = new Item(palavra, categoria);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE! I REALLY LOVED THE QUICK REPLY!

Answer (score 0):

One little edit to the answer above- you need to define i as an int in the beginning of your for loop.

```
for(int i = 0;
```

etc. etc.

Comment: i was already defined as an int outside of the for loop. Check near the top.

Comment: Thank for the reply, man. I defined up there because I thought that would be the problem since the program is stoping just after I press enter after the second input